# HTTPS support for Volley Android networking library

Tags: android, http, rest, https, android-volley

I have a project making REST calls to an HTTPS backend
It which works fine on some devices, and breaks on others.

This is the error I get:

> com.android.volley.NoConnectionError:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted:
>   ssl=0x78004ee8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
>   error:140770FCSL routinesSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
>   (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:766 0x731f5d5c:0x00000000)

Looking at the Volley documentation, they mention

> "You can include your own HTTPStack ( to handle SSL connections [...])"

**Has someone done this for volley ? If so can you please share your changes ?**

Notes: The Certificate is signed by a valid entity which was already in the trusted certificates of the devices.

Comment: Note: for reference, this is the networking library I am talking about: https://github.com/smanikandan14/Volley-demo

Comment: Which port are you connecting on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my solution:

In class `Volley` in method

```
public static RequestQueue newRequestQueue(Context context, HttpStack stack)
```

locate the following text:

```
stack = new HurlStack();
```

Then change this line to:

```
stack = new HurlStack(null, createSslSocketFactory());
```

where method `createSslSocketFactory()` is defined as following:

```
private static SSLSocketFactory createSslSocketFactory() {
    TrustManager[] byPassTrustManagers = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new X509Certificate[0];
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
        }
    }};

    SSLContext sslContext = null;
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = null;
    try {
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, byPassTrustManagers, new SecureRandom());
        sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, StringUtils.EMPTY, e);
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, StringUtils.EMPTY, e);
    }

    return sslSocketFactory;
}
```

I know that this is not secure, but I use it for testing purposes only. You can improve the security by accepting only certificates from your servers.

Comment: This is not working in my project. It is saying Request.finish:

Comment: @droid_dev: for `getSSLSocketFactory`, you can refer to [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154115/android-volley-self-signed-https-trust-anchor-for-certification-path-not-found). Hope this helps!